# How to solve this error " (pre:svcFault) Service Fault"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, soap, savon

I am trying to call a SOAP api using Savon gem. I am getting the following error: "(pre:svcFault) Service Fault" [image: error image] 
I created both the header and message for the request. 
Here is the request sent from SoapUI: [SoapUI request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czdPt.png).
i am getting a true response from SoapUI.
My code is shown below:

```
class SoapApi
    require 'savon'
    def self.initialize 
        header = {
            "ebmCID" => "9366498d-bc79-4fad-be2b-fa1a0e84241a", 
            "ebmMID" => "9366498d-bc79-4fad-be2b-fa1a0e84241a",
            "ebmRTID" => "9366498d-bc79-4fad-be2b-fa1a0e84241a",
            "ebmSID" => "FMobile-FCUBS",
            "ebmTimestamp" => "2019-06-10T12:27:46.1623586Z",
        }
        message = { 
            customerId: '00653473'
        }
        client = Savon.client(
                    :wsdl => "https://192.168.176.103:8012/tevs/pp.pm.evs.Customer_1.2?wsdl",
                    :ssl_verify_mode => :none
                    )
        response = client.call(
                    :get_account_list,
                    :soap_header => header, 
                    :message => message
                    )
        return response
    end
end
```

And here i am calling the above method:

```
#index.html.erb
<%=
  SoapApi.initialize
  puts @response 
%>
```

Comment: check what request is getting created before calling it.

Comment: now I don't remember how, but there is a way to check the generated request. See if anything is missing

Comment: @DeepakMahakale first thak you, and i dont know how to check what request is getting created, i appreciate your help.

Comment: As I described in my response, add the key/value pairs `{ :log => true, :log_level => :debug, :pretty_print_xml => true }` to your client definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you able to create a valid call using SoapUI (https://www.soapui.org.)? Try this first and make it work.
Next create a call from a plain ruby script - without Rails - which sends the same functional XML as you did in SoapUI before.
Third embed this code into your RoR application.

You can put the following in your client definition for better logging:

```
client = Savon.client(
  :wsdl => "https://192.168.176.103:8012/tevs/pp.pm.evs.Customer_1.2?wsdl",
           :ssl_verify_mode => :none,
    log: true,
    log_level: :debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
    )
```

Compare the output with your working SoapUI example.

Comment: i am using SoapUI and i am receiving a valid response(now you can see my SoapUI request above in the picture), and after adding log, log_level, and pretty_print_xml, i still have the same error, anw thank you for your help

Comment: Now I'd look for the differences between the SoapUI generated XML and the Savon XML. I usually prefer *not to use* the WSDL. Instead I'm building my clients "from scratch". That gives me more flexibility. If nothing else works there is still the option to send raw xml.